# What does this debugging message mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors

Can someone please help me out. I'm not sure what this error message I'm getting when I try and run certain screens means. Whenever I try to run my main menu I get this, but if I run the instructions viewcontroller as the initial scene I don't get this. I see in that code it says something about a highscore, so I took out the code I had for displaying my highscore on the main menu and it's still doing this. Can anyone tell me what this looks like?

So confused.
Thanks. Shen Hutah

```
2014-02-25 01:49:44.479 game[7914:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0xa26de60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key highScore.'
    *** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017aa5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180


    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0152d8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0183a6a1 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x011ee9ee -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
    4   Foundation                          0x0115acfb _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 88
    5   Foundation                          0x0115a253 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
    6   Foundation                          0x011bc70a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
    7   UIKit                               0x0053da15 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0153f7d2 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x017a5b6a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
    10  UIKit                               0x0053c56e -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1417
    11  UIKit                               0x003ae605 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
    12  UIKit                               0x003aedad -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
    13  UIKit                               0x003af0ae -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    14  UIKit                               0x003af5b4 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    15  UIKit                               0x002d79fd -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 66
    16  UIKit                               0x002d7d97 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
    17  UIKit                               0x002d802d -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    18  UIKit                               0x002e289a -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
    19  UIKit                               0x00295cd0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1851
    20  UIKit                               0x0029a3a8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    21  UIKit                               0x002ae87c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
    22  UIKit                               0x002aede9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    23  UIKit                               0x0029c025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x023362f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x02335e01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x01725d65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x01725a9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x0175077c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x0174fac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x0174f8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    31  UIKit                               0x00299add -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    32  UIKit                               0x0029bd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    33  game                                0x0000d6ed main + 141
    34  libdyld.dylib                       0x02c8a70d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: I guess you are missing to add relevant frameworks which causes such errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error can be due to the following reasons:

1. You have assigned inccorect class to your view controller.
2. The property(in your case highScore) might be deleted from the class but is still hooked up in IB.

Make sure that you have done the above correctly.